# How to delete an element from Arraylist in C#

Tags: c#, .net, arraylist

Lets say I have this loop and I put the data in an `ArrayList`:

```
int Num1 = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text);
int Num2 = Int32.Parse(textBox2.Text);
ArrayList ItemList = new ArrayList();
while (Num1 <= Num2)
{
    ItemList.Add(Num1);
    Num1++;
}
```

And I have another loop to read my `Arraylist`:

```
foreach (int item in ItemList)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add("Number " + item.ToString() + ",");
}
```

Which gives this result:

```
Number 1,
Number 2,
Number 3,
Number 4,
```

I need to remove the last comma in the last item and get this result:

```
Number 1,
Number 2,
Number 3,
Number 4
```

I've tried this:

```
foreach (int item in ItemList)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add("Number " + item.ToString().Trim(',') + ",");
}
```

But it doesn't work. Can someone please tell me what I did wrong, and how I can fix it?

Comment: That's a bit confusing. This is not really about deleting an element from an array, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See if this works for your purposes:

```
var result = string.Join("," + Environment.NewLine, itemList.ToArray());
```

Forgot the "Number" part:

```
var result = string.Join(", " + Environment.NewLine, itemList.ToArray().Select(x => "Number " + x));
```

Comment: I was about proposing the same. Neat, clean, simple.

Comment: Of course, instead of adding integers 1, 2, 3... you would need to a "Number 1", "Number 2", "Number 3" .... to your ArrayList instead.

Comment: That will use the `String.Join(string, params object[])` overload, so the result is `"System.Collections.ArrayList"`.

Comment: Yeah either call itemList.ToArray() or just use a List<string> instead of the ArrayList

Comment: Thanks for answer but it doesn't work for me i got this system.collections.arraylist

Comment: @downloaddowload I was under the impression that you would use .ToArray() before the join, but see the edit to fix that issue.

Comment: oh thanks a lot it's work  and how can i add my String Number because the second line of code doesn't work for me

Comment: @downloaddowload I realized I made that mistake, that too is fixed just now.

Comment: @JoshL. Thanks a Lot for help and sorry if i waste your time

Answer (score 3):

```
listBox1.Items.Add("Number " + item.ToString() + 
ItemList.IndexOf(item) == ItemList.Count - 1 ? string.Empty : ",");
```

Comment: What's the complexity of `IndexOf()` again? Was it `O(N)` maybe? And what if we are doing this in a loop?

Comment: thanks but it dosn't work i have a red line this part  ItemList.Count()

Answer (score 0):

you should not modify the item of your collection inside a foreach.

May be you should try to modify your collection `ItemList` before the `foreach` that shows your result .

You can make somthing like this (before the foreach that shows your results):

```
ItemList[ItemList.Length-1] = ItemList[ItemList.Length-1].SubString(0,ItemList.Length -2);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
foreach (int item in ItemList)
{
    if (listBoxOne.Items == null)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add("Number " + item.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(",\n" + "Number " + item.ToString());
    }

    //Or more simply below
    listBoxOne.Items.Add = listBoxOne.Items == null ? ("Number " + item.ToString()) : (",\n" + "Number " + item.ToString());
```